# unable to see ROS repository during ROS Hydro install on Mint 13 Maya

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfully installed ROS Hydro Desktop Full on my Ubuntu box and now I'm trying to install the bare bones ROS base on my robot's computer which is running Linux Mint 13 Maya.

I must be missing something fundamental, because I'm not getting past step 1.4 on the Hydro installation page:  [full URL removed from post due to low karma]wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu

My starting point:

```
$ apt-cache search ros-hydro
$
$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maya
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 13 Maya"
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maya
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 13 Maya"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.2 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
$
$ uname -a
Linux myhostname 3.2.37-compulab.cm-itc #2 SMP Tue Mar 12 13:36:04 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$
```

My install attempt:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [full URL removed from post due to low karma]packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
$
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
deb [full URL removed from post due to low karma]packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
$
$ wget [full URL removed from post due to low karma]packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
--2009-12-31 23:33:24--  [full URL removed from post due to low karma]packages.ros.org/ros.key
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 140.211.166.134
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|140.211.166.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1162 (1.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

100%    [===========================================================================================================================================================================>] 1,162       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2009-12-31 23:33:24 (11.9 MB/s) - written to stdout [1162/1162]

OK
$
$ apt-cache search ros-hydro
$
```

As you can see, apt-cache is still not seeing the ROS repository I just added.  What did I do wrong?

Thanks for any help you can provide.  I'm stuck with Mint 13 on this robot computer, so I have no choice but to use it.

Kurt W. Leucht
(software developer in Central Florida)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116081/unable-to-see-ros-repository-during-ros-hydro-install-on-mint-13-maya/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 486 on 2014-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When adding a new repository, you must do `apt-get update` to pull down the cache files for the new repository so that they show up in your local cache.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-01-09**:
Thanks so much.   That was a little embarrassing since the 'apt-get update' was clearly in the ROS install instructions.  In my defense, I got confused and thought it wanted me to perform an 'apt-get upgrade', which crashed my system last time I tried it.  This was purely a newbie mistake.  Thanks for your prompt and polite answer to my dumb newbie question.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-01-09**:
Since my problem turned out to be not specific to my OS, I'm going to attempt to change the title and tags of this question so future newbies will find it more easily.